# node.js ffi import constant

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffi

Let's say I have a shared object libfoo.so, which has the following source code:

foo.h

```
extern cont int fooconst;
```

foo.c

```
const int fooconst = 5;
```

Using the `ffi` package from node.js, how can I access `fooconst`?

This is a simple example, but what in what I'm trying to do, fooconst is a big struct with pointers in the fields, which I do not want to re-write in javascript.

edit: I do not want to modify the C code.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you would need a function to return this value. Otherwise you won't be able to access it.

So in your `foo.c` you write:

```c
const int fooconst = 5;

int getNum(){
    return fooconst;
}
```

And in your nodejs app:

```
let ffi = require("ffi");
let ref = require("ref");

let int = ref.types.int;

let fooconst = ffi.Library("./libfoo.so", {
    "getNum": [int, []]
});

let myConst = fooconst.getNum();
```

Comment: @nigel you may need to create a separate c library that wraps the c library you're accessing in order to expose a function to node.